# Is Islamweb.net a trusted website?

Tags: fatwa

Is islamweb.net website trusted? Which Madhab do they follow? I searched that question but did not find any reliable answer.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be? Similar to Islamonline at a time variouse known scholars usd to give fatwa there. The site is even less biased than for example islamqa.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Islamweb.net is reliable. They don't necessarily follow a particular madhhab just like IslamQA.info.

For more information visit Islamweb's [About us](https://www.islamweb.net/en/index.php?page=aboutus) and [Fatawa](https://www.islamweb.net/en/fatawa/?tab=3) page.

Of course, I personally don't agree with many of their views, but that doesn't mean they don't mention valid opinions regarding issues.